# Generar numero consecutivo en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hola buenas quería asignar letras fijas a una columna en mysql y generar un numero consecutivo, dicho numero ya le genero con el siguiente código:

```
<?php

 $consulta = mysqli_query($mysql,'SELECT MAX(num) as num FROM num_ficha LIMIT 1');
 $consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


 // Si el codigo actual esta vacio o es 0, se convierte en 1.
 // En caso contrario se le suma +1.
 $codigo = (empty($consulta['num']) ? 1 : $consulta['num']+=1);
 echo 'El codigo actual es: '.$codigo;

 $consulta = mysqli_query($mysql,'INSERT INTO num_ficha (num) VALUES ('.$codigo.')');
 if(!$consulta){die('Error');}

 ?>
```

Comment: Has generado el número correctamente, según dices, y en el código parece que quieres insertarlo en la tabla `num_ficha`... ¿cuál es el problema en sí? En la pregunta hablas de asignar letras fijas, y no explicas nada al respecto...

Comment: Quiero poner las letras ESP fijas a la columna num de la tabla num_ficha

Comment: Entonces puedes poner hacer algo así: `$sql="INSERT INTO num_ficha (num) VALUES ('ESP$codigo')"; $consulta = mysqli_query($mysql,$sql);` Para más claridad, he creado una variable `$sql` aparte. Y ten en cuenta que esa variable empieza y termina por comillas dobles `"` no por comillas simples.

Comment: Usar `max` para ver el valor máximo en una columna y usarlo como consecutivo suele terminar en problemas de concurrencia, dos inserciones "simultáneas" con el mismo valor, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Esta una forma:

```php
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $cont = $row['cont'] + 1; // incrementa   
        $num = sprintf("%'.02d", $cont); // formato con 5 digitos
        $codigo = "OBJ-CAM" . "-" . $num; // se concatena con el año actual
    }
```

Y haces el insert con el campo $codigo